# php update query and order

Tags: php, mysql

please i am having issues concerning the order of records after updating.
I have two pages `home.php` and `settings.php`.
 The `home.php` contains result from a mysli select query.

```
$getid = $getdata['user_id'];
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM  posts 
                            WHERE `user_id` = ' $get_id' 
                            ORDER BY date_added DESC 
                            LIMIT 15 ");
```

The records being selected are `id` `username` `notes` `date_added`, these records are successfully displayed in  `desc` order.

On my `settings.php` i'm allowing the user to update their username,while updating their username,i also run a update query that change the username on the `notes` table. New username are successfully updated both on the `user` table and `notes` table. But the unfortunate things is,when i get back to the `home.php` , the notes are not displayed in `desc` order again. it is displaying the notes from the top of the table.

The update query function(called from the `settings.php`):

```
function update_user($update_data){
    $con = db();
    global $session_user_id;
    $update= array();
    array_walk($update_data, 'array_sanitize');
    foreach ($update_data as $field => $data) {
        $update[] = '`'. $field . '` =\''.$data .'\'';
    }
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `users` SET " 
                       . implode(', ', $update) . , 
                      " WHERE `user_id` = '$session_user_id'");

    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE notes SET username = 
                                (SELECT `username`
                                FROM  users 
                                WHERE user_id = $session_user_id
                                ) 
                        WHERE user_id = $session_user_id ");
}
```

I have tried ordering by `date_added`, it's not working still.
Kindly help me out, thanks.

Comment: The order does not depend on the username at all. Run the query in mysql directly to check if it gives the good result there. Also it is generally a bad idea to concat you SQL using user input as it is sensitive to sql injection...

Comment: This is obviously note the code you are actually running! The first query would obviously fail as `$getid` != `$get_id` and `WHERE user_id = ' $get_id'` has a space in front of the id ?????? **We can only help debug what we see**

Comment: avoid using `global` instead parse the variable as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
you have to change date format to UNIX_TIMESTAMP to apply order by in 
query 
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * ,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_added) as date FROM  posts 
                        WHERE `user_id` = ' $get_id' 
                        ORDER BY date DESC 
                        LIMIT 15 ");
```

Comment: the data type of date_added is timestamp